# Stellar.toml checker passes all tests, but asset information not published

Tags: token, stellar-laboratory, stellar.toml, verification

I'm trying to get information about an asset on the public network published. Using [this](https://stellar.sui.li/toml-check/) stellar.toml checker, I get success on every test. Additionally, when I check my token on stellar.expert, it does display the proper information, including the logo filename, but not the logo itself. On StellarTerm, none of the information is published. I've looked around the documentation but can't seem to find any guidance for how to fix this issue -- let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you!

Comment: I hope you got it working. Just a quick thanks for the toml checker tool. It helped me identify the problem with mine. I had the wrong account for my issuing currency! https://stellar.sui.li/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to get in touch with the team that runs StellarTerm. They probably have to pull the info from your stellar.toml into their system and need to trigger that process somehow.